# How to authenticate a cURL request to the Binance API?

Tags: curl, binance

Trying to learn about crypto.

I would like to manually create an order to Binance.

I have the API key and secret, I can create requests to get the price and other info, but I am not sure how to authenticate requests to create an order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a signature of your params (sign it using your private key) and then include the signature with the request (as well as rest of the params).

The [official docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv3order) have an example of creating the signature using `openssl` and then sending the request (containing the signature and other params) using `curl`.

```
[linux]$ echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
(stdin)= c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

```
(HMAC SHA256)
[linux]$ curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A" -X POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order' -d 'symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71'
```

---

For a JS implementation, see for example [source](https://github.com/Ashlar/binance-api-node/blob/00409ef35e18467b87bceb7b657481e88efa8ccc/src/http-client.js#L174) of the `binance-api-node` NPM package. It uses the native `crypto` package and its `createHmac()` method.

```
const signature = crypto
  .createHmac('sha256', apiSecret)
  .update(makeQueryString({ ...data, timestamp }).substr(1))
  .digest('hex')
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.